# Neo4J cypher: collect intermediate node properties (path)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a data lineage related graph in **Neo4J** with variable length path containing intermediate nodes (tables):

```
match p=(s)-[r:airflow_loads_to*]->(t)
where s.database_name='hive'
and s.schema_name='test'
and s.name="source_table"
return s.name,collect(nodes(p)),t.name
```

Instead of returning the nodes between s.name and t.name as a path, I want to return an **array** of the **name** property of all nodes in the path (in the order of traversing)

I **probably** have to use collect, but that is not possible on a path...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

changing the last line to

```
return s.name, [n in nodes(p) | n.name] as arrayOfName, t.name
```

should do the trick

Comment: Great that, worked! But now I have a 2nd problem as the result set contains loops that I want to omit. New question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59735441/neo4j-cypher-remove-loops-from-flattened-resultset