# Neo4J cypher: remove loops from flattened resultset

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This is an extension of [the following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59734396/neo4j-cypher-collect-intermediate-node-properties-path):

I have a data lineage related graph in **Neo4J** with variable length path containing intermediate nodes (tables) as an array:

```
match p=(s)-[r:airflow_loads_to*]->(t)
where s.database_name='hive'
and s.schema_name='test'
and s.name="source_table"
return s.name, [n in nodes(p) | n.name] as arrayOfName,t.name
```

Now, this resultset contains **loops that I want to omit**. I can '*remove*' these loops without the flattening ArrayOfName result by running:

```
match p=(s)-[r:airflow_loads_to*]->(t)
where s.database_name='hive'
and s.schema_name='test'
and s.name="source_table"
return s.name, min(size(r)) as pathlen, t.name
order by pathlen
```

However, when I add ArrayOfName back, the resultset contains all rows again.
I guess this means chaining the results somehow, using the *pathlen as a filter* or *preventing that loops exist* in the path p at all. 
**But I am stuck on how to accomplish this...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try

```
p=shortestPath((s)-[r:airflow_loads_to*]->(t))
```

because it seems that is what you need

Comment: I tried, but got the error 'The shortest path algorithm does not work when the start and end nodes are the same. '
But after adding an additional filtering clause where s<>t id did indeed work!